# to_i method doesn't convert string

Tags: ruby, watir

I get the text containing the sum from an element:

```
sum = browser.div(:class => 'single sort', :index => 0).div(:class, 'amount').text
```

Then I have to compare `sum` with another integer, but `sum` is still a string:

```
>> sum = browser.div(:class => 'single sort', :index => 0).div(:class, 'amount').text
=> "7 671 \u0420"
>> puts sum.class
String
>> sum.gsub!(/[^0-9]/, '')
=> "7671"
>> puts sum.class
String
>> sum.to_i
=> 7671
>> puts sum.class
String
```

How can I convert `sum` to an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to assign the new value to `sum`:

```
sum = sum.to_i
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the results in this way:

```
sum = sum.to_i
```

I suggest to use `Integer(sum)` instead of `.to_i` method to raise an exception if you try to convert a not number string.

```
nil.to_i = 0
"".to_i = 0

Integer("") 
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): ""
    from (irb):1:in `Integer'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/nico/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

`String#to_i` returns a new Object (which is the only sensible implementation; think a moment about what would happen if `String#to_i` magically changed the object's class).

So, to assign the integer value to your `sum` variable, use

```
  sum = sum.to_i
```

or (better) introduce a new variable for your integer value:

```
  sum_as_integer = sum.to_i
```